# Runge Kutta - MIT web equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I do not understand the following equation I found [here](http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/Differential_Equations_Notes/node5.html). (see equation 14)

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{df(y,t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$

I have troubles with the last equation.

Comment: It looks like they're just using the chain rule for a multi-variable function

Comment: Thank you, that actually makes sense. It didn't click immediately that y is actually also dependent on t.